# The space between rows inside Recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager is messed up

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recyclerview with a gridlayoutmanager attached to it. The columns are spaced correctly but the rows are messed up. The space between each row seems to change each time I scroll up and down.
[image: Picture showing the problem]

This is where I setup the recycler view and the grid layout manager:

```
  var inflater = view.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var rootLayout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_linear)
    var heroListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hero_list_tab_card, rootLayout, true)

    //get the recycler view
    var heroListRv = heroListView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_heroes)
    heroListRv.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(view.context, 4)
```

Here is hero_list_tab_card:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_primary_attribute"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="30sp"
           android:textAllCaps="true"
           android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
           android:text="@string/test"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_primary_attribute"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/dotabuddy_icon"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_heroes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_primary_attribute"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the actual hero elements that are populated inside the grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_heroimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dotabuddy_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_heroname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
        android:text="@string/test"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_heroimage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_heroimage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_heroimage"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please let me know if you want me to post any other information. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: for clarification Im talking about the huge gap between row 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a constraint from the `ImageView` to your `TextView` as well, also if you want to add space between your item I recommend using `ItemDecoration`.

As you're in a `ConstraintLayout` you can specify the ratio of your image using `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"` for example or `4:3` if you want a square.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_heroimage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dotabuddy_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_heroname"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_heroname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_heroimage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: My problem is the huge gap between rows 4 and 5 as seen in the picture? Im not sure if setting a ratio to the images will help. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: that might be an issue with how you set your constraint, you should add more constraint on your `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>`, take a look at the constraint I've add in the XML and try this out also as pointed out by @hai, use `android:maxLines="1"` to avoid little bumps between your rows

Comment: Hmm I tried adding what you suggested. Setting up constraints like the one you posted only made it stretch out vertically. Here are some better pictures of the problem: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/360599912737538050/705065918786437220/unknown.png https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/360599912737538050/705065910171336774/unknown.png

Comment: Yep my bad, it's because of the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` change them as `0dp` (for width) and the height you'd like for example `60dp`. Did it resolve the gap between the rows ?

Comment: Wow setting the width to 0dp seems to have done the trick! Thanks a lot man!! Here is what it looks like: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/521402419595444225/705074162674434088/unknown.png

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you should fix maxLine for this TextView and be sure the image you load into ImageView same height or you should fix height of ImageView.

Comment: Hey sorry I was talking about gaps - like between row 4 and 5 in the picture.